# Visual studio 2019 Removed project but still get reference in Temporary ASP.NET Files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, temporary-files

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I created a project and then decided that I didn't need it and removed it from my solution. The solution builds successfully. However, when I run the remaining projects, I get this error message in the YSOD:

> The type or namespace name 'RemovedProject' could not be found. Source
> File: c:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\vs\63f72506\347f2602\App_Web_index.cshtml.ce0b5a11.bhx-cdpd.0.cs

If I delete the file, then it just appears back with the same reference but with a different extension before the 0 (ce0b5a11.bhx-cdpd in this example). VS is generating that file with that reference for some reason.

I've tried deleting the .vs folder in the solution folder, as well as the bin and obj folders of the remaining projects. I also deleted the temporary files in `C:\Users\\%user%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_08106da7\ComponentModelCache` after shutting down VS, but that did not resolve the issue.

Any ideas on why VS keeps generating that file or how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can try to check the Web.config, if there include the deleted namespace.